# How to call popup form after successful submission?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a filling form, so i need when user fill in the required fields and click submit button, popup form will appear "You are successfully recorded"

Any ideas to implement this problem?

```html
<fieldset class="field-set col col--full" style="false">  <label class="field-set__label"><?php echo _("Name"); ?></label>
  <input type="text" class="field" name="fio" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="field-set col col--full" style="false">
  <label class="field-set__label"><?php echo _("Company name"); ?></label>
  <input type="text" class="field" name="company-name" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="field-set col col--full" style="false">
  <label class="field-set__label"><?php echo _("E-mail"); ?></label>
  <input type="email" class="field" name="E-mail" value="" placeholder="" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="field-set col col--full" style="text-align:center;">
  <button id="callMe" class="button button--prime"><?php echo _('Submit'); ?></button>
</fieldset>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#summer-party-form").submit(function() {
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    var btn = $(this).find("input[type=submit]");
    var oldBtnTitle = btn.prop("value");

    btn.prop("disabled", true).prop("value", "<?php echo _("Sending ");?>...");

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/engine/summerparty.php",
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          result = '<?php echo _("<big><big><big>You are recorded</big></big></big>"); ?>';
          $("#summer-party-form .grid").hide();
        } else {
          result = msg;
          btn.prop("disabled", false).prop("value", oldBtnTitle);
        }
        $('#summer-party-form .note').html(result);

      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: You can do an `alert()` (or a modal) inside `success: function(msg) {`

Answer (score 0):

In your style tags:
    @import "compass/css3";

In a script tag:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
$(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
    $(this).remove(); 
});
}, 4000);
```

Within the body tags:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 text-center>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<strong>Success!</strong> Thank you for registering!
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Redirect to a "successful submission" page or simply reload the page on submission and this will pop up saying thanks for registering. it will close itself after 4 seconds.

Obviously use some indenting on the code to save your eyes.

You need to make sure to import bootstrap too.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```